# Php search same values in different array keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

This it´s my little script, but don´t get right results at the moment :

```
<?php

    // Delimiters betweeb data "*" elements in each data delimiters ","
    $data_string="house1,403,phone1*house2,404,phone2*house3,403,phone3*house4,405,phone3";
    // Explode $data_string for "~" delimiter
    $data_exp=explode("*",$data_string);
    //

    // Loop 1
    foreach($data_exp as $data_1)
    {
        $data_exp_compar=explode(",",$data_1);

        // We want see the elements with the same data in common in second position (403,404,etc)
        $data_common_1[]=$data_exp_compar[1];
        $data_common_2[]=$data_exp_compar[1];
    }

    $a=array_values(array_intersect_key($data_common_1,$data_common_2));
    $b=array_count_values(array_intersect_key($data_common_1,$data_common_2));

    foreach($a as $aa=>$values)
    {
        echo $aa;
        print "<br>";
    }

?>
```

The idea in this script. It scans the data inside "$data_string", as you can see, all data delimiters is "*" and inside each data we have elements with "," as delimiter

I want get this output results and in this format :

```
PRODUCT Id: 403 (2 Actually)

1-  house1,403,phone1
2-  house3,403,phone3 

PRODUCT Id: 404 (1 Actually)

1 - house2,404,phone2

Product Id: 405 (1 Actually)

1 - house4,405,phone4
```

As you can see the only element for compare it´s in the second position and it´s product´s id

I try many things but i can´t get works, or get finally results as i want show

Thank´s in advanced for all , regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them first then another `foreach` loop for printing result

```
$data_string="house1,403,phone1*house2,404,phone2*house3,403,phone3*house4,405,phone3";
$data_exp = explode("*",$data_string);

$group = []; // Initialize group array
foreach($data_exp as $data_1)
{
    $data_exp_compar=explode(",",$data_1);
    $group[$data_exp_compar[1]][] = $data_exp_compar; // Group by the number key after exploding
}

// Loop to each group, then print desired format
foreach ($group as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Product ID: ' . $key . ' (' . count($value) . ' Actually)<br>';
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        echo ++$k . ' - ' . implode(',', $v) . '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using array_map and array_filter functions. Let me know if you have questions about this.

```
<?php

// Prepare data and input
$id = 403;
$data = "house1,403,phone1*house2,404,phone2*house3,403,phone3*house4,405,phone3";

// Convert string data to array
$data = explode("*", $data);
$data = array_map(function ($row) {
    return explode(",", $row);
}, $data);

// Search the array
$response = array_filter($data, function ($row) use ($id) {
    return $row[1] == $id;
});

print_r($response);
```